# dxhtml ganttchart Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular5

I am following dxhtml ganntchart official documentation [dxhtml link](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__loading.html)

Here I want to compare my previous task text with current task text which user is trying to enter and in case if both the task text i.e previous and current is  same then current task should not be added .

```
// model for task

export class Task {

    id: number;
    start_date: string;
    text: string;
    progress: number;
    duration: number;
    parent: number;
}

// gannt.component.ts 

 gantt.attachEvent("onBeforeTaskAdd", function(id,item){

    //any logic here

    return true;

});
```

[link for code](https://github.com/DHTMLX/angular2-gantt-demo)

Comment: What have you attempted? Stackowerflow is not here to write code for you.

Comment: I just want to know the approach that how can I compare the previous task text with current task text.